# What is the best Practice / Industry Standard for storing documents with social security numbers, date of birth, financial records, etc?

Tags: content-security-policy, standards, sensitive-data-exposure

I am building an app that will be storing sensitive info (SSN's, DOB's, Financial Information, Credit Cards, etc.

Is there a standard that will cover all these items and what is the best approach to storing? Should blobs be used?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly are you interested in? The security implications of storing these things? In that case, I don't see what kind of difference using a blob would make.

Comment: User uploads documents with Social, DOB, and possibly credit card information on them. Just need to be in compliance with security standards in storing them. Trying to figure out the best approach, DB & Encryption?

Comment: Also just found SSAE16 Type II which may be needed

Comment: Does anyone have a 3rd party API that could be utilized?

Comment: Generally, the security questions requirements are mainly a matter of management rules (who can do what). The technologies to use are just consequences: if the sysadmin shall not be able to read some data then it must be encrypted. Be it in blob or not is just not pertinent here - it may be later, but for now you did not say enough.

Answer (score 2):

This is very broad and as such, it's a little hard to exactly cover everything that applies to each. However, I'll try to cover the ones that I know apply.

- ***Credit card*** information is generally governed by PCI DSS (Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard) as the credit card industry likes to regulate themselves and not be regulated by governmental regulations.
- ***Financial Information*** is usually covered by SOX (Sarbanes Oxley) which is a governmental regulation.
- ***SSN & DOB*** is PII (Personally Identifiable Information) which can be handled by PCI DSS, but is probably covered by another set of policies entirely.

SSAE16 is more of a security framework that provides a standard of security, which is very useful and can be used to protect this information and comply with the various regulations.